# Tables forming circular reference

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-normalization

I am Designing a database for school management system. Database will hold data for multiple schools. Tables that I am designing are forming circular reference..It looks like this :

School - SchoolId (Pk), SchoolName, RegistrationNo,.....

Department - DeptId (Pk), SchoolId(Fk), DeptName,...

Teacher - TeacherId (Pk), DeptId (Fk), SchoolId(Fk), Name,....

Schools will have different Departments and Teachers. Teachers will belong to specific department.

How can I avoid this circular reference..

Any help/ suggestion will be appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: I don't see a circular reference. Circular references are where `a` references `b` and `b` (directly or indirectly) references `a`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So you mean to say that if a reference b, b reference c and c reference a is circular reference.. And if a reference b as well as c and b reference c is not circular reference..  can tables and relations that I have created create problem in future or this is normal and I can continue with this.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the FK on Teacher that references to SchoolId, because given a Teacher, you can access his school through the FK to the Department table.

However, as The Unbeliever says, this is not a circular reference, just a normalization error.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.. but the Fk on Teacher that references Dept is nullable as a teacher can exists that does not belong to any department. In that case I wont be able to find out that to which school particular teacher belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so (based on your comment) we have a situation where not all teachers belong to departments. There are two ways to model this.

First is to make both `SchoolId` and `DeptId` in `Teacher` nullable, and have a check constraint that ensures that exactly one of those columns is not null. So a departmentless teacher has a `SchoolId` and a teacher in a department just has a `DeptId`.

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher (
    TeacherID float not null primary key,
    DeptId float null,
    SchoolId float null,
    constraint CK_Teacher_School_or_Dept CHECK (
         (DeptId is null and SchoolId is not null) or
         (DeptId is not null and SchoolId is null)
    ),
    constraint FK_Teacher_School FOREIGN KEY (SchoolID)
          references School (SchoolID),
    constraint FK_Teacher_Dept FOREIGN KEY (DeptId)
          references Department (DeptId)
)
```

The second way to deal with this is to add a unique key constraint in `Department` on both `DeptId` and `SchoolId`, and then apply a foreign key on *both* of these columns from `Teacher` to `Department`. When `DeptId` is null, this foreign key constraint isn't checked and so everything is fine. When `DeptId` is not null, then it serves to enforce that the `SchoolId` column in `Teacher` matches the `SchoolId` in department.

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
    DeptId float not null primary key,
    SchoolId float not null,
    constraint FK_Department_Schools FOREIGN KEY (SchoolId)
          references School (SchoolID),
    constraint UQ_Departement_WithSchool UNIQUE (DeptId,SchoolID)
)

CREATE TABLE Teacher (
    TeacherID float not null primary key,
    DeptId float null,
    SchoolId float not null,
    constraint FK_Teacher_School FOREIGN KEY (SchoolID)
          references School (SchoolID),
    constraint FK_Teacher_Dept FOREIGN KEY (DeptId,SchoolID)
          references Department (DeptId,SchoolID)
    /* Optional - still have the FK on just DeptID if you think it
       better documents the "real" relationship */
)
```